# Unsupervised loss function in Keras

Tags: machine-learning, keras, unsupervised-learning

Is there any way in Keras to specify a loss function which does not need to be passed target data?

I attempted to specify a loss function which omitted the `y_true` parameter like so:

```
def custom_loss(y_pred):
```

But I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "siamese.py", line 234, in <module>
    model.compile(loss=custom_loss,optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 911, in compile
    sample_weight, mask)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 436, in weighted
    score_array = fn(y_true, y_pred)
TypeError: custom_loss() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

I then tried to call `fit()` without specifying any target data:

```
 model.fit(x=[x_train,x_train_warped, affines], batch_size = bs, epochs=1)
```

But it looks like not passing any target data causes an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "siamese.py", line 264, in <module>
    model.fit(x=[x_train,x_train_warped, affines], batch_size = bs, epochs=1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1435, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1322, in _standardize_user_data
    in zip(y, sample_weights, class_weights, self._feed_sample_weight_modes)]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 577, in _standardize_weights
    return np.ones((y.shape[0],), dtype=K.floatx())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

I could manually create dummy data in the same shape as my neural net's output but this seems extremely messy. Is there a simple way to specify an unsupervised loss function in Keras that I am missing?

Comment: I think you are missing the point, what would your unsupervised loss do exactly? What exact computation?

Comment: I am trying to compare the similarity of two different outputs from the neural net. The more similar they are the lower the loss should be.  To be more specific, I am attempting to re-implement the neural network described in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.02193)

Comment: I think you should use the dummy data.... yes...it's ugly and I don't like it either... but I can't see a solution.

Comment: the second error related to your input/output data, you need to use `numpy.array`. You can use `x_train` as a target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best solution is customizing the training instead of using the `model.fit` method.

The complete walkthrough is published in the [Tensorflow tutorials page](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_training_walkthrough#train_the_model).

Answer (score 2):

Write your loss function as if it had two arguments:

1. `y_true`
2. `y_pred`

If you don't have `y_true`, that's fine, you don't need to use it inside to compute the loss, but leave a placeholder in your function prototype, so keras wouldn't complain.

```py
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    # do things with y_pred
    return loss
```

---

**Adding custom arguments**

You may also need to use another parameter like `margin` inside your loss function, even then your custom function should only take in those two arguments. But there is a workaround, use lambda functions

```py
def custom_loss(y_pred, margin):
    # do things with y_pred
    return loss
```

but use it like

```py
model.compile(loss=lambda y_true, y_pred: custom_loss(y_pred, margin), ...)
```